# How to open this file?

Tags: php, linux, filenames, non-ascii-characters

Unfortunately I've allowed users to upload files to the server without sanitizing its names first (Linux, PHP, MySQL).

One of the uploaded filename is "**E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasTípicas.zip**" (it's correct in the MySQL database, UTF-8 encoded).

But when I try do a fopen() in PHP I can not find this file. Depending on the locale (LANG) I retrieve different filenames, as such:

```
    $ export LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8
    $ ls ../web/downloads/E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasT*
    ../web/downloads/E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasTÃ­picas.zip

    $ export LANG=pt_BR.ISO-8859-1
    $ ls ../web/downloads/E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasT*
    ../web/downloads/E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasT▒?­picas.zip

    $ export LANG=C                             
    $ ls ../web/downloads/E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasT*
    ../web/downloads/E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasT????picas.zip
```

Can someone help me in discovering how can I open this file using PHP?

PS: of course, I've tried utf8_encode, utf8_decode, no sucess.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What encoding is your PHP file in? How do you `fopen()` the file, where does the file name come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a script that finds files and renames the file without corrupted characters (non-alphanumeric and underscores)

Check scandir to find the files http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Check this thread to find non-alphanumeric characters [PHP Regular expression - Remove all non-alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426976/php-regular-expression-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters)

So, you will get clean file names and as written on your database. If needed you can do the same operation on your database field too.

Comment: If the underlying filesystem supports UTF-8, filenames will work fine without cleanup even from a PHP script. It just has to be done right.

Comment: I have the clean-up filename routine written in PHP; I can aplly it to the filenames stored in the database and in the filesystem. But I can not figure why **rename($old_filename, $new_filename)** fails saying it can not find the file with accented characters (the $old_filename). BTW, I'm using Debian Linux, EXT4 filesystem.

Comment: And it is almost impossible to do by hand. There are thousand of files in this situation (thanks God it's number is not growing anymore)!

Comment: Check this thread, you can rename files by a regex search : http://superuser.com/questions/70217/is-there-a-linux-command-like-mv-but-with-regex  So, if you are not able to rename files with corrupted characters you can match them with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using:

```
$ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Which means in php:

```php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
```

Comment: Same strange thing:
        # export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        # ls ../web/downloads/E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasT*
        ../web/downloads/E_M_20-06-2013_14-15_ComidasTÃ­picas.zip

Comment: Try typing `locale -a` to get the list of installed locales. If en_US.UTF-8 is missing you should install it first.