# remove accents and filter out non-alphanumerical chars

Tags: php, regex, string

How can i filter the non alphanumerical characters out of a string, but keep the accents untouched ?

example:

```
$string = "présentation d'un texte, avec des accents (en français!) & autres..."
```

Should be replaced by:

```
$string = "présentation dun texte avec des accents en français  autres"
```

Comment: Googled my problem. Didn't find solution.

Comment: No shit sherlock. I've tried reading manual, i suck at regex. I could find how to filter out alphanumerical chars but not accents. Your replies are useless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
$str = "présentation d'un texte, avec des accents (en français!) & autres...";
echo preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\s\p{N}]+/u', '', $str);
//=> présentation dun texte avec des accents en français  autres
```

Character class `[^\p{L}\s\p{N}]+` means match 1 or more of characters are **NOT**:

1. unicode letters
2. unicode digits
3. space

`/u` flag is for matching unicode letters.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "présentation d'un texte, avec des accents (en français!) & autres...";
echo preg_replace('%[^\p{L}\s\p{N}]++%u', '', $string);
```

Output:

```
présentation dun texte avec des accents en français  autres
```

Explanation:

- `\p{L}` - all alphabetic characters
- `\p{N}` -- all numbers
- `u` - to treat the pattern string as UTF-8

The regex says: replace everything that's not an alphabetic character or number or a whitespace character with nothing (`''`).

Useful link: [Unicode character reference](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF)

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/82085)

Comment: As per OP `d'un` needs to become `dun` not `d un`

Comment: @anubhava: Ah, I missed that. Thanks, I've now updated the answer. :)

Comment: @anubhava: I didn't copy your answer. I actually used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16427088/1438393) as reference but didn't notice the space between `d` and `un` before [you commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737183/remove-accents-and-filter-out-non-alphanumerical-chars/20737282#comment31071969_20737282). And I couldn't find a cleaner way to avoid the space and used `\s`. I've given you an upvote for being the first one to tackle the issue, though. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Tested using PHP Version 5.4.20 and PHP Version 5.2.3-20070601

```
<?php
$text = "présentation d'un texte, avec des accents (en français!) & autres...";
$new = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ  ]/", '', $text);
echo $new;
?>
```

Will produce `présentation dun texte avec des accents en français autres`

As per posted: with no space between `d` and `un`

```
présentation dun texte avec des accents en français autres
```