# Remove punctuation from string in other language PHP

Tags: php

I want this string to remove all special characters.  I've tried below but the arabic characters are also being removed.  These strings will be dynamic, so i can't use `str_replace`.

```
$video = ".()[]{}holakouee,sex,psychology,dr farnoody,dr mitra babak,dr azita sayan,dr Maryam mohebbi,هولاکویی,دکتر فرهنگ هلاکویی,دکتر فرنودی,دکتر میترا بابک,دکتر آزیتا ساعیان,دکتر مریم محبی,دکتر سروش,دکتر انوشه,دکتر سارا ";


$videoDesc = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/", '', $video);
        echo $videoDesc;
```

How do i solve?  I only want letters, numbers and commas regardless of the language.

Comment: Which special characters do you want removed?

Comment: Define 'special characters'.  Typically you either define a whitelist of everything to allow, or a blacklist of everything you want to exclude.

Comment: What's the desired output of `$videoDesc`?

Comment: check edit , i only want letters,numbers and commas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Regular expression - Remove all non-alphanumeric characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426976/php-regular-expression-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-characters)